# How can I get a $_GET variable in a .js.php file?

Tags: php

So on my main page I have

```
<?php
require_once('config.inc.php');
require_once($rootdir . $dirsubfolder . 'navbar.php');
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&sensor=true"></script>

<script src="php/findme.php"></script>

<div class="hero hero-unit" style="padding: 0; padding-top: 3%;">
    <div id="search" class='input-append'><input id="setNewDistance" class="span3" type="text" placeholder="Set Distance In Meters">
        <button class='btn btn-info' id="changeDistance" type="submit">Search
        </button></div>
        <p class='alert-info' id="stopsfoundtext"></p>

    <div id="gmaps"></div>
</div>

<?php
require_once($rootdir . $dirsubfolder . 'footer.php');
?>
```

Then in Findme.php I have

```
<?php

/* Include neccesary files */
require_once('config.inc.php');
$gPlantSite = $_GET['plantsite'];
/* Connect to Database */

$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_BASE);

/* Prepare Database statement */

if ($stmt = $mysqli -> prepare("SELECT route_id, Latitude, Longitude, Title, Weekday_Day, Weekend_Day, ADO_Day, Weekday_Night,
    Weekend_Night, ADO_Night, Direction_Of_Bus, 
    What_Shift FROM Routes WHERE Plant_Site = ?")) {
/* Bind param to search for */

 $stmt -> bind_param('s', $gPlantSite);

/* Execute and hope it works */

$stmt -> execute();


/* Bind the results to variables */

$stmt -> bind_result($gRoute_Id, $gLatitude, $gLongitude, $gTitle, $gWeekdayDay, $gWeekendDay, $ADODay,
$WeekdayNight, $WeekendNight, $ADONight, $gDirectionOfBus, $gwhatShift);

/* Leave connection open so that it may be queryd on the client side */

include "../js/findme.js.php";

}

?>
```

But it still doesn't seem to get the $_GET from the php file, anybody have any idea im running out of ideas here

I just need it to get the $_GET I tried using the idea posted as the answer but that doesn't seem to be working for me.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Where is the js? Above is all PHP.

Comment: Have you tried using Ajax?

Comment: @mkaatman that file is <?php require_once() ?> in my .js.php file

Comment: @XCritics Can you also paste that file? If you're trying to access the query results from javascript, an AJAX call might be more appropriate than the require_once.

Comment: @mkaatman ok I just left the office so I won't be able to till I get home but then I will!

Comment: What's the difference between a .js.php file and any other .php file? Does your webserver process these differently?

Comment: @barman it's so I can run PHP in a .js file and include it through <script src="blah.js.php"></script>

Comment: @XCritics it is a plain PHP file, not anything special.

Comment: @Hiroto it's special to me :<

Answer (score 1):

You could just include your js.php file inside this file.

if you do this:

```
// .. other code ..
$stmt->bind_param('s', $gPlantSite); // at the bottom..

include "js.php"; // at the end of the file
```

then you will also then have access to $_GET inside this file.

**EDIT**

It will not work as you want at the moment:

```
<script src="php/findme.php"></script>
```

this means you are going to execute the findme.php script, but you are not providing any query string here, so $_GET will always be empty.

to provide anything via $_GET you will need to provide to to the script tag like this:

```
<script src="php/findme.php?plantsite=something"></script>
```

$_GET['plantsite'] will then be populated with the value 'something' inside Findme.php.

As you are including your findme.js.php file inside Findme.php, that script too will have $_GET populated. hope this helps :)

Comment: So then on my actual page do i call it in script src or include

Comment: I edited my original post trying to do what you said can you tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: what error do you get if any?